# Which Fallout 3 items are sought-after by NPCs?

Tags: fallout-3

Some of the items in Fallout 3 are special because some NPC wants to collect them.  What are they?  Who wants them?  What are the special conditions associated with turning them in to the NPCs, if applicable?

If it's not already clear, **the answer(s) will contain spoilers**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Scrap Metal**

- Walter, water filtration tech
- Megaton
- 10 caps/piece
- Available after fixing the three leaky pipes around Megaton

**Scrap Metal 2**

- [This Old House](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/This_Old_House)
- Winthrop in the Underworld at the Museum of History
- 5 pieces of scrap metal to exchange for 1 stimpak, 1 rad away, or 1 rad-X

**Pre-War Books**

- Yearling, scribe
- Arlington Library
- 100 caps/piece
- Available after reaching the library

**Sugar Bombs**

- Murphy, chem cooker
- Northwest Seneca Metro
- 15 caps/piece normally, 30 after passing a speech check; also access to Ultrajet
- Available after reaching the Metro station

**Cameras**

- Rothchild, scribe
- Citadel Laboratory
- 100 caps/piece and 25 exp/piece
- Available after completing *Who Dares Wins*, the last Broken Steel quest

**Various**

- [The Outcast Collection Agent](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Outcast_Collection_Agent)
- Protector Casdin at Fort Independence
- Scrap Metal
- Various weapons and armour
- Produces:

  - 5.56mm ammunition
  - Frag grenades
  - Rad away
  - Stimpaks

Answer (score 18):

1. [Blood Packs](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Packs) - For the unmarked repeatable quest [I Want to Drink Your Blood](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/I_Want_to_Drink_Your_Blood), available after completing the quest [Blood Ties](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Ties) from [Vance](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vance_(Fallout_3)) in [Meresti Station](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Meresti_Station)
2. [Cameras](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Camera) - For the unmarked repeatable quest [Getting Ready for Prime Time](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_Ready_for_Prime_Time) in the [Broken Steel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Broken_Steel) DLC from [Scribe Rothchild](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Reginald_Rothchild) in [The Citadel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel)
3. [Fire Ant Nectar](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Ant_Nectar) - For the unmarked repeatable quest [Nectar Collecting for Fun and Profit](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Nectar_Collecting_for_Fun_and_Profit), available after completing the quest [Those!](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Those!) from [Doctor Lesko](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Lesko) in [Marigold Metro Station](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Marigold_Metro_Station)
4. [Brotherhood of Steel Holotags](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Brotherhood_of_Steel_Holotag) - For the unmarked repeatable quest [Collecting Holotags](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Collecting_Holotags) from [Scribe Jameson](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Scribe_Jameson) in [The Citadel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel), only availble until you start the quest [Take it Back!](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Take_it_Back!), unless you have the [Broken Steel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Broken_Steel) DLC, which allows you to  to continue after that quest.
5. [Nuka-Cola Quantum](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Nuka-Cola_Quantum) - For [The Nuka-Cola Challenge](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Nuka-Cola_Challenge) sidequest from [Sierra Petrovita](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sierra_Petrovita) in [Girdershade](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Girdershade) ([Ronald Laren](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ronald_Laren) wants them too.)
6. [Pre-War Books](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pre-War_book) - For the unmarked repeatable quest [Yearning for Learning](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Yearning_for_Learning) from [Scribe Yearling](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Scribe_Yearling) in [Arlington_Library](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Arlington_Library)
7. [Scrap Metal](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Scrap_Metal) - For the unmarked repeatable quest [Walter's Scrap Metal](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Walter%27s_Scrap_Metal) from [Walter](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Walter_(Fallout_3)) in [Megaton](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Megaton), availble after the umarked quest [Treatment](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Treatment)
8. [Sensor Modules](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sensor_Module) - For the unmarked repeatable quest [Getting Ready for Prime Time](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_Ready_for_Prime_Time) in the [Broken Steel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Broken_Steel) DLC from [Scribe Rothchild](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Reginald_Rothchild) in [The Citadel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel)
9. [Sheet Music Books](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sheet_Music_Book) - Only during the quest [Agatha's Song](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Agatha%27s_Song) from [Agatha](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Agatha) in [Agatha's House](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Agatha%27s_House)
10. [Sugar Bombs](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sugar_Bombs) - For the unmarked repeatable quest [Murphy's Bombing Run](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Murphy%27s_Bombing_Run) from [Murphy](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Murphy) in [Northwest Seneca Station](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Northwest_Seneca_Station)

Naturally, killing the NPC will make you unable to deliver anymore items to that NPC

Source: [The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/)

Comment: Lots of can be converted into StimPacks/ammunition for:
http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Outcast_Collection_Agent

Comment: Scrap metal can also be turned in at http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/This_Old_House - but The Outcast Collection Agent is better value, and Walter gives you XP.

Comment: @Douglas, edit that stuff into the CW answer; that's why I made it CW.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus I don't have enough rep yet to edit CW...

Comment: @Douglas, unless something is different about this site (with respect to other SE sites) you only need 100 rep to edit CW, and you now have more than that.

Comment: I think I see the problem now: This answer isn't community Wiki. And I missed the "the CW answer" sorry.

Comment: @Douglas, 'sall good, live and learn, &c.

Answer (score 1):

Walter in Megaton collects scrap for caps.

Vance in Arefu collects blood packs for caps.

Sierra Petrovita collects Nuka Cola Quantums for a quest, a recipe, and eventually caps.

Most of these repeatable quests are listed [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_quests), near the edge of the page on the fallout wiki.

Fallout 3 is a massive game. This question needs to be tightened in scope, a little. It's too broad.